# Socket.io not working with Heroku

Tags: node.js, sockets, heroku, socket.io

I have looked at all of the Stack Overflow questions regarding the problem. Still, I am unable to run Socket IO along with Heroku. I have looked at https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1542 and this https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/wiki/Socket.IO-and-Heroku. The sockets run locally.

index.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"]);
  io.set("polling duration", 10);
});

var server = http.listen(port, function(){
});
```

The running sample is here. https://curly-octo-woof.herokuapp.com/

Comment: What errors are you getting in your browser console?

Comment: GET http://curly-octo-woof.herokuapp.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1441405280642-0 400 (Bad Request) Error in socket.io-1.3.6.js